# Apache Royale Jewel TextArea : how to have a carriage return ? (for text to go to a new line)

Tags: textarea, carriage-return, apache-royale

Is it possible to have a carriage return (for text to go to a new line) in the `<j:TextArea>` when hitting *return* key ? (actualy it seems ignoring it).

SDK used is 0.9.8#2556

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a bug. Thanks for reporting, just fixes it in my last commit.